# Why is my circuit not providing the right voltage to my motor?

Tags: voltage, pcb-design

I have a circuit which is supposed to vibrate a vibrating motor. The circuit is fairly simple and uses a BJT to step up the current to the motor. The motor also has a capacitor and diode in parallel to protect from surges.

Here's a picture of the circuit:

[image]

When I hook everything up, the motor doesn't turn on. I tested the voltage drop between the leads and it only read 0.2-0.4V. Do the values for the resistors/capacitors make sense? I'm fairly new to circuit design so I may have made a very simple mistake.

EDIT: I forgot to mention the motor needs to run around 3V with 75mA

Comment: A motor's stall current is always higher than the current at which it runs once it spins up. If the motor is designed to run off 3V and you have 3.3V supply, then why are you powering it from 5V with a resistor?  What's the model of the transistor?

Comment: Did you tried to apply an higher voltage at the base of the transistor? If your control circuit cannot provide more than 3.3V you may consider using a MOSFET instead of a transistor.

Comment: @NickAlexeev The 3.3V source is actually from a pin on a IOIO-OTG microcontroller board. The pins are rated for a maximum of 20mA. Using what I learned in my electronics classes, the best option of upping the current is to use a BJT. Is there an easier way?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira, see my comment above

Comment: What is that 33Ω resistor supposed to be doing...?

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle, The resistor is there to control the voltage to the motor. I don't want it running at 5V, so I need another voltage drop between the source.

Comment: @maxmackie And how do you think the resistor will do that?

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle, well, I could be wrong, but the 5V source at the top will supply (5V-V_c). In my calculations a while ago I found that difference to be too high, so I added the resistor to tune the drop.

Comment: So, according to Ohm's Law, what would the voltage drop be across a 33Ω resistor?

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle, `(5V-V_motor)/I` right?

Comment: @maxmackie  Well, I wasn't suggesting to power the motor directly from the microcontroller I/O pin.  But, I suspect that the same board ([this?](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Dev/Android/IOIO-OTG-v20b.pdf)) has an +3.3V DC power output from the same regulator that powers the micro.  Of course you shouldn't pull too much current from it to avoid blowing up the regulator or causing a reset on the microcontroller.  Having said that, perhaps you should build and test your transistor circuit with the motor separately from the I/O board, and power it from the desktop power supply.

Comment: No. That holds true for LEDs which are current driven devices with a fixed forward voltage drop at the diode junction.  If your motor is running with 75mA then the voltage drop would be V=RI = 33*0.075 = 2.475, so the motor would be getting 2.525V. HOWEVER, that is only true when the motor is running.  The motor isn't running, so it will be needing the "stall current" to get it to start moving.  This will be much higher than the running current.  More current = more voltage drop over the resistor = less voltage for the motor = not running.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, that's actually not a bad idea. However I'd need to turn the motor on and off using a digital signal on the IOIO-OTG. Is there a component which would allow me to do that?

Comment: @maxmackie Ditch the 33Ω resistor and replace the +5V with +3.3V from the controller board's regulator. Keep everything else the same (BJT).

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle, so both the base and the collector would be connected to a 3.3V source? Just want to make sure I understand before giving it a go.

Comment: @maxmackie No, the collector would be connected to the 3.3V *supply* through the motor, and the base would be connected to a 3.3V *signal* - the two, though at the same potential WRT ground, are very different things.  The 3.3V *supply* is always on, the 3.3V *signal* is switched on and off.

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle, ahh so the digital signal at the base (connected to the pin) will dictate the flow of current through the BJT, while the motor will be connected to the 3.3V supply (so, no 20mA current restriction) directly?

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle  The +3.3V on that board comes from [MIC5216](http://www.micrel.com/_PDF/mic5216.pdf).  It can do 200mA with 500mA peak.  Perhaps, the 75mA motor will not blow up this regulator.

Comment: @maxmackie  We've been here for half an hour.  Perhaps, it's time to bust out the breadboard, turn on the power supply, and burn some transistors.  That should stave off the analysis-paralysis.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, yeah I'm planning on doing that. Just want to make sure by IOIO and my motors will be safe seeing as I don't have many replacements (read: none).

Comment: @maxmackie  Then keep the expensive board out of it.  You can create the digital on/off signal with a switch.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, true. This is why I asked questions. I'm so new to this field that I miss the basic stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 33Ω resistor is causing a big problem.  According to Ohm's Law, the voltage drop across a resistor is proportional to the current flowing through it:

$$
V=RI
$$

So when your motor is running and pulling 75mA the voltage drop across a 33Ω resistor would be (33 * 0.075) 2.475V.  That leaves just 2.525V to run your 3V motor.

However, that only holds true when the motor is actually running.  A motor doesn't arrive in its packaging already spinning - you have to get it to start moving, and that means overcoming its inertia.  This requires more current than the normal running current, and is known as the "stall" current, since the motor isn't spinning at the time (it's stalled).

That stall current could be many times the running current.

As an example, let's assume a stall current of 150mA.  What would the voltage drop through the resistor be then?

$$
V=RI = 33×0.15 = 4.95V
$$

4.96V from a 5V supply? That's not good - only 0.05V left for the motor.  There's no way that's going to start moving with just 0.05V.

So what do you need to do?  Well, simply put: ditch the 33Ω resistor and replace it with a power supply of the right voltage.

You are controlling the BJT from a controller board that runs at 3.3V.  That board will have its own 3.3V regulator on it to power the main chip.

Assuming that regulator is capable of providing enough current to drive the motor, then you can draw your main current from it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD3lhW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, if the regulator on the board isn't powerful enough you will need to provide your own regulator to drop the voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzPCSq.png)</sup>

---

Edit: Apparently the regulator on your board is a [MIC5216](http://www.micrel.com/_PDF/mic5216.pdf) which can supposedly supply up to 500mA. Assuming your motor has a stall current below 500mA (less the current required by the rest of the board) you should be safe enough to use it to supply the motor.

Comment: This is incredibly insightful. Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: A quick question, in your circuits you've changed the type of BJT, the capacitor value and the base resistor value. The transistor I have is an `2N2222`. Is there a way to keep that in the circuit or should I buy the `2N3906`?

Comment: That BJT is just the default in CircuitLab. I didn't bother changing the value.  Any small signal NPN will do fine - the 2N2222 is a very common (and good) choice of NPN.

Comment: Cool. Should I swap the 1K resistor for a 470 one? I'm not sure why you changed it.

Comment: Reducing the resistor value would allow more current to flow through the BJT.  A 1KΩ might strangle the current a little (or it might not).  Better to "open the tap" wider than you need to let the water flow than block the pipe.

Comment: I was just brainstorming some ideas. My IOIO is powered by a Koala Protoboard (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10614). I could use the 3.3V source on that board. However, it says 3.3V maxes out at 100mA. In that case I should take it from the regulator on the IOIO? I assume that regulator steps up the current?

Answer (score 0):

With the 1kohm base resistor, the transistor will be 'fully on' at 3.3v (base current is about (3.3-0.7)/1000 = 2.6mA), so that isn't the problem.

The 33ohm resistor however will drop 2.5v at 75mA. As such, there's less than 1.8v left for your motor. You should remove it. You can limit the current by either lowering the supply voltage (use your 3.3v in stead of the 5v supply for the motor), or (more complex), setting the base current so that the transistor provides exactly the right current. Obviously in your case, the first scenario is most straight forward.

Comment: No no no, you want to get rid of the 33Ω resistor altogether - it is not a suitable method for dropping a voltage with a variable current device.